# Does cuda toolkit leave its installation files behind?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, package-management, cuda

Before installing cuda toolkit.I had about 25 gibibytes of free space on my root directory.After installing cuda using [deb(network installer)](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=2004&target_type=debnetwork) and a manual reboot after installation I noticed that  only about 15 gibibytes of free space disk space was available in root dir.As cuda toolkit usually occupies only about 5 gibibytes of space i assume the installer probably failed clean itself up(2*5GiB=10GiB).Advise me on how to rectify the issue.
The following commands did not help

`sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove`

PS:I installed cuda so that i can render blender scenes with my gpu.is it necessary to install the entire toolkit for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the location you installed cuda, (/usr/local/cuda?) for a directory with a name like cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01_1.0-1_amd64.deb   That just contains all the separate deb files, and may be removed, as it's not necessary for running CUDA.

Comment: For me, the folder was `/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-4-local/`

Answer (score 1):

> Does cuda toolkit leave its installation files behind?

Weird way to phrase this question.

`apt` will leave configuration files if you did not use `purge` when you removed it and it will also never remove personal created files. So if you created a file it will still be there.

1 dubious part of the installation from the link:

```
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
```

`apt` does not know about this command so do check if that got removed.

Comment: cuda-repository-pin-600 is a 190 byte file........

Comment: If this is 1 large file you might find it with `locate`. Do a `sudo updatedb && locate | grep cuda` to search for anything cude related.